# Firebase events amount different from Big Query

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, analytics, firebase-analytics

My company launched a test and we are triggering events every time the user enters a certain navigation route.
On Firebase we have about 100 events logged, but when we try to filter by userId (all users participating on the test) using bigQuery, the number of events in way lower, how is that possible?

Here is my query:

```html
SELECT * FROM `[projectName].analytics_157738294.events_intraday_20200304` WHERE user_id IN (
'1',
'303240',
'2466',
'243',
'143774',
'167104',
'535319',
'644114',
'283377',
'350247',
'15073',
'90154',
'113299',
'133079',
'141390',
'148977',
'181653',
'247968',
'274420',
'341127',
'370285',
'385091',
'395329',
'435660',
'462866',
'492174',
'521397',
'554326',
'611972',
'620803',
'660836',
'273432')
```

And here are the events im trying to find:
[image]

Comment: could you please extend your question to include sample SQL query and event tracking code?

Comment: Just edited my original question

Comment: When i run that query, it gives me all the events up to today of the selected users, but if i filter all the events by only the 'feed' ones, they show less events than what the firebase csv shows..

Comment: Hi, just to make sure I understand: The query above (where your filter by user_id) yields the expected results, right?, but if you also filter by "Name of event" you see less results, correct? Can you please also share the query where you filter by "Name of event" and the expected vs the actual result set?